# Omission of "but also" in "not only ..., but also ..."

Tags: conjunctions

I've seen some topics related to this correlative pair 'not only..., but also ...', but I'm still not quite sure if it's correct to use a comma without any conjunction in the following construction:

> "The American commoditization of time **not only** serves as the basis for a "time is money" mentality, it can lead to a fixation on timelines that plays right into the hands of smart negotiators from other cultures".

In this excerpt, the comma between '*mentality*' and *'it can lead'* joins the two independent clauses without any conjunction. Can we use commas to join two clauses without any conjunction?

I was thinking that the conjunction 'but' should separate those clauses, because 'not only..., but also ...' is a correlative pair, so it is always used as a set. Am I wrong? Or I guess there should be at least a semicolon between them.

Answer (score 1):

In your query sentence, I would regard the segment I have marked off with curly brackets simply as a sort of emphatic preamble or introduction to the clause that follows it:

> "The American commoditization of time **{** not only serves as the basis for a "time is money" mentality **}**, [it] can lead to a fixation on timelines that plays right into the hands of smart negotiators from other cultures."

This seems to me to be a more useful way of analysing the sentence than trying to find an explanation for the supposedly anomalous absence of a conjunction or semicolon.

Comment: You mean the segment in "curly brackets"? I don't really understand how the segment including a subject 'it' can act as an emphatic preamble in a sentence. Is it grammatically okay to use the correlative pair "not only .. but" without the conjuction "but"? So the sentence goes to "The American commoditizatin of time can lead to a fixation on timelines." Am I right? quite confusing to me...

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I've adjusted the position of the closing curly bracket so that it encloses only the emphatic preamble. The 'it' that I have enclosed in square brackets stands in for the main subject of the sentence.